# Excel VBA How to use a Chartobjects object?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I'm trying to collect chartobjects using a chartobjects object, but I'm not sure what method I need to use to change which charts are inside the chartobjects.

Here's the general code structure I'd like:

```
dim ExampleChart as chartobject
dim ChartCollection1 as chartobjects
dim ChartCollection2 as chartobjects

set ExampleChart = Activesheet.ChartObjects.Add( 0, 0, 400, 300)
set ChartCollection2 as Activesheet.ChartObjects

'add ExampleChart to ChartCollection1 ?
'remove ExampleChart from ChartCollection2 ?
```

Comment: When you say group do you mean selecting more than one chart and then grouping under the shape format option?  `ChartObjects` is the collection of all charts (a chart sits within a  `ChartObject`) on a sheet.  They're automatically added to the collection when you create the chart.

Comment: By group I meant collection. What's the purpose of being able to `dim` a variable as `ChartObjects`  if it's just the charts in a sheet?

Comment: So you can reference all the charts on a sheet by stepping through the collection? Writing `ChtObjs` is faster than writing `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects` each time?

Comment: You can add the charts to a regular `Collection` object if you just want to group them into a container.

Answer (score 0):

The example of charts regrouping below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReGroupCharts()
    Dim shpGroup As Shape
    Dim ch(1 To 5) As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim a()
    
    '1st phase - group
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select  'error occurs if selected non-contiguous cells
    For i = LBound(ch) To UBound(ch)
        'create 5 charts with shift
        ch(i) = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(i * 50, i * 50, 400, 300).Name
    Next
    ' group them
    Set shpGroup = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(ch).Group

    '2nd phase - regroup
    
    ReDim a(1 To 3)
    j = 1
    For i = LBound(ch) To UBound(ch)
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
            a(j) = ch(i)        ' select odd elements into array a() from array ch()
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    shpGroup.Ungroup    'ungroup initial group
    
    'make group with chart names from a()
    Set shpGroup = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(a).Group
    
    ' shift new group right
    shpGroup.Left = shpGroup.Left + 300
End Sub
```

**After 1st phase**
[image]

**After 2nd phase**
[image]